# C Arithmetic Expression Calculator

Tags: c, calculator

I have to implement an expression calculator without using stacks. I'm just really confused as to how to start this. If anyone could explain to me what I'm supposed to do, I would really appreciate it. I realize this isn't the best question, nor is it specific, but I'm just having a really hard time even getting started.

I just don't understand (at all) how I'm supposed to use recursion to implement this calculator. How am I supposed to use the m_exp l_op h_op etc that they defined? I just don't understand at all, sorry for the lack of better words :(

[image]

Comment: Recursive descent would be one way (that does use the call stack, but doesn't use an explicit stack object).

Comment: Anyone know how I'm supposed to use m_exp l_op h_op etc? Honestly I just need an explanation on what the heck is going on...

Comment: Did you miss the class?

Comment: If OP didn't miss the complete course, this is pure sadism...

Comment: Can someone please tutor me on skype or something? My professor didn't talk about the assignment at all, he just reads off his slides which was on basic UNIX and C syntax... I'm willing to pay $50/hr, anyone willing to help me let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the expression `2.3 * 4 - 7.8 / 9`, you want to build a *parse tree*:

```
                         "-"
                    ._____|_____.
                    |           |
                   "*"         "/"
                 .__|__.     .__|__.
                 |     |     |     |
                2.3    4    7.8    9
```

It can be generated by recursively applying the definitions given in the last part of the exercise:

```
Start:  EXP
Rule 4: EXP L_OP M_EXP
Rule 5: M_EXP "-" M_EXP
Rule 2: M_EXP H_OP M_EXP "-" M_EXP H_OP M_EXP
Rule 6: M_EXP "*" M_EXP "-" M_EXP "/" M_EXP 
Rule 1: 2.3 * 4 - 7.8 / 9
```

A way of approaching this is making a series of functions that handle each rule:

```
void m_exp();
void   exp();
etc...
```

Each of these functions will try to match the next part of the input, and update some global variables accordingly. Wikipedia has a [great article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser) about recursive descent parsers, which includes a C example.

> How exactly am I supposed to "recurisvely apply the definitions given in the last part of the exercise", the stuff you wrote?

Here is an excerpt from the aforementioned [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser), slightly modified:

```
// Implements Rule 1
void num(void) {
    // Reads a number
}

// Implements Rule 2
void m_exp(void) {
    num();
    while (sym == '*' || sym == '/') {
        getsym();
        num();
        // Does more work...
    }
}

// Implements Rule 4
void exp(void) {
    m_exp();
    while (sym == '+' || sym == '-') {
        getsym();
        m_exp();
        // Does more work...
   }
}
```

Rules 5 and 6 are already built-in. Rule 3 is the entry point.

Here, the [tail recursion] has been replaced by loops. Note how `exp` calls `m_exp` many times, and `m_exp` does the same with `num`.

Comment: Hey I really appreciate the help, though I am still very lost at this point. So can I start from the beginning? When I ask the user for the expression, let's say he gives what you said, 2.3 * 4 - 7.8 / 9 . How exactly am I supposed to "recurisvely apply the definitions given in the last part of the exercise", the stuff you wrote? I do have some experience with recursion in java but am just very new to this whole C thing. As far as I'm aware, recursion is when you call the method itself, until a base case is reached. Can you tell me how recursion can be used to read in the input and make the

Comment: Can you tell me how recursion can be used to read in the input and make the parse tree? Sorry for being so ignorant! :( I do understand how the rules work thanks to your example, but I am not sure how to actually implement these rules, and how I'm supposed to use these rules in "recursion".

Comment: Ah i figured it out. I'm supposed to implement my own getsymbol method

Comment: My connection is awful and I've been unable to reply. You're on the right track. Search for anything you don't understand and remember there is no such thing as a stupid question (as long as you've thoroughly searched before!).

Comment: Got it working!!! XD Too bad it's an hour late after the deadline, oh well. Thanks again, wouldn't have gotten it working without this forum :)

Answer (score 2):

what you have there is the definition of a grammar http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_grammar

You can read it as:

1. m_exp can be a number
2. m_exp can be another m_exp followed by an h_op followed by a number
3. exp can be m_exp
4. exp can be an exp followed by an l_op followed by an m_exp
5. l_op can be + or -
6. h_op can be * or /

Basically this is defining how your evaluate function should work for.

Following this rules your function may evaluate inputs as:

```
Rule 1: 2
Rule 2: 1 * 2
Rule 4: 3 + 1 * 5
Rule 4: 2 * 5 + 1 + 2
...
```

To convert your grammar in a recursive function note that the literals in the grammar will be the simple base case in your recursive function.

According to @MBlanc answer you can convert each no terminate rule into a recursive function.

Answer (score 0):

> Anyone know how I'm supposed to use m_exp l_op h_op etc?

What you're looking at there is a Bachus-Naur Form (BNF) description of the grammar of the expressions you're going to interpret. Looking at the more complicated example in section 3:

An h_op is either a * or / token (the | means "or"). In other words, it's a multiplicative operator.

An m_exp can have one of two forms. It's either a num (presumably a number token), or it's an an m_exp followed by an h_op followed by a num. In other words, it's a multiplicative expression, defined recursively: 3*4, 5/7, 3*5/17, etcetera, including the simplest case of just a single number. They could have used | to show the two alternatives, but they decided it would be clearer to call them out on separate lines; it means the same thing either way.

Knowing that, you can see that an exp is an additive expression -- a group of multiplicative expressions tied together with + or - tokens.

If you know what you're doing, the BNF can be used fairly directly as instructions for building a recursive descent evaluator. Your instructor *should* have covered this, or should cover it well before the assignment is due.

Answer (score 0):

Read up on [recursive descent parsing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser), once you've got the parser going (it's not hard) make the functions return the value for the expression recognized.